# Update textbox value when pop window close

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to change value of textbox when popup window close, currently i am doing it with session variable but it does not update value without postback event

```
  'Popup Page Code
Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Session("partname") = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(2).Text.ToString()
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "CloseWindowScript", "window.close();", True)
End Sub
```

Session value is called in other page

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
      If (Session("partname") <> Nothing) Then
        txtpartname.Text = Session("partname")
      End If
    End Sub
```

I want textbox value to change as soon as the popup window close

Answer (score 0):

When you select a value in dropdown list, save it in a viewstate. and use that viewstate in pageload to set the value of dropdown list.

```
in button_click event 
//ddl.selectedvalue = "Test";

viewstate["ddlValue"] = ddl.selectedvalue;

 In page_load event

if(viewstate["ddlValue"] != null)

{ddl.selectedvalue = viewstate["ddlValue"].Tostring(); }
```

Comment: im opening popup window through javascript

  function basicPopup() 
    {
    popupWindow = window.open("lookup.aspx", 'popUpWindow', 'height=300,width=600,left=100,top=30,resizable=No,scrollbars=No,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=No');
 
    }

Comment: ok..then try using Response.Cookies ("ID").Value = TextBox1.Text

Comment: Then after closing the pop up window IDGet = Request.Cookies("ID").Value

Comment: You can also use Hidden Field if using JavaScript

Comment: isnt it the same thing? how it will update textbox value on closing popup window

Comment: yes but it will not change the value on textbox with any trigger or postback event

Comment: pls refer this link http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/09/popup-update-refresh-parent-child.html  it describes how to Open PopUp Window In Asp.Net And Update Refresh Parent Child Values using ClientScript And RegisterStartupScript.
A popup window is opened  from aspx page and updating values in parent window from child or popup window using javascript and ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript.

Answer (score 0):

From the pop-up window you try storing the value as follows, this is just an example :

```
Response.Cookies ("ID").Value = TextBox1.Text
```

When the popup page is closed you can retrieve that value as

```
IDGet = Request.Cookies("ID").Value
```

Comment: I can do this with session as well, it doesnt update without a poostback event